# set correct uibutton state after deleting cell from tableview in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm new to Swift and it's quite hard for me to wrap my head around this particular problem. So please be a little patient, if I cannot communicate the point right away. ;-) Thx!

Basically I have a kind of To-Do-List in a UITable. The cells have a UIButtons (with a custom class) as a "checkbox". I store the button state in a Dictionary like so:

```
var buttonState = [listItem1 : true, listItem2 : false, ...]
```

The Dictionary is also stored to `NSUserDefaults`. This is all working fine. My problem is, that when I delete cells with the `UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete` function and reload the table after with `self.tableView.reloadData()`, the button states come up wrong. In the above example, if i deleted listitem1, listItem2 will be *displayed* as true. In fact the stored value is still false. I guess this must have something to do with the indexPath.

Note: I do update the Dictionary before `self.tableView.reloadData()` to `buttonState[listItem1] = nil`. Meaning I do have the correct value for each ListItem in the dictionary. Also if I reload the view completely (i.e. go back one screen in the simulator and reload the list from scratch) all button states come up right.

How can I get the right button state right after deleting a tablecell without reloading the whole screen?

Hope all of this makes sense somehow! ;-)

//Seb

The relevant code in the UITableView:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellItem", forIndexPath: indexPath) as customCell

    //Identify Button with Tag
    cell.checkbox.tag = indexPath.row

    // Set Label
    switch indexPath.section{
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(kleidung[indexPath.row])"
    case 1:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(hygiene[indexPath.row])"
    default:
        cell.textLabel?.text = nil
    }
    // Set Cell State
    cell.onLoadSet()
    return cell
}


// DELETE TABLE ROW
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){

        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            kleidung.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            let fixedPackItems = ",".join(kleidung)
            packlisten![rowCount].setValue("\(fixedPackItems)", forKey: "kleidung")
        } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            hygiene.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            let fixedPackItems = ",".join(hygiene)
            packlisten![rowCount].setValue("\(fixedPackItems)", forKey: "hygiene")
        }
        context.save(nil)

        if var storedToDoItems: AnyObject! = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("packItems") {
            var itemString = storedToDoItems as? Dictionary<String, Bool>
            state = itemString!
            println(itemString)
        }

        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
        identifier = "\(currentCell.textLabel!.text!)\(rowCount)"
        state[identifier] = nil
        println(state)
        let checkedItems = state as Dictionary
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(checkedItems, forKey: "packItems")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

        self.packlisteTable.reloadData()

    }
}
```

And in the customCell class:

```
@IBAction func checkboxButton(sender: CheckBox) {

    // Change Button State
    if sender.isChecked == true {
        sender.isChecked = false
    }else{
        sender.isChecked = true
    }

    //Retrieve stored state
    if var storedToDoItems: AnyObject! = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("packItems") {
        var itemString = storedToDoItems as? Dictionary<String, Bool>
        if itemString != nil {
            state = itemString!
        }
    }

    //Add new State to Stored
    identifier = "\(textLabel!.text!)\(rowCount)"
        state[identifier] = sender.isChecked

    //Store state
    let checkedItems = state as Dictionary
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(checkedItems, forKey: "packItems")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

}

func onLoadSet(){
    identifier = "\(textLabel!.text!)\(rowCount)"
    //Set state from stored State
    if var storedToDoItems: AnyObject! = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("packItems") {

        if storedToDoItems != nil {
           var itemString = storedToDoItems as? Dictionary<String, Bool>
            if itemString![identifier] != nil {
                checkbox.isChecked = itemString![identifier] as Bool!
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show your code for `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: Swift or Objective-C ?

Comment: Swift. And I just posted the code... Thx!

Comment: Just checked: after deleting a cell, the tableview does indeed reload and also func onLoadSet() gets executed with the right button states retrieved from UserDefaults...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found it. Unbelievable how simple it was in the end!

I just added an else satement to:

```
func onLoadSet(){
identifier = "\(textLabel!.text!)\(rowCount)"
//Set state from stored State
if var storedToDoItems: AnyObject! = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("packItems") {

    if storedToDoItems != nil {
       var itemString = storedToDoItems as? Dictionary<String, Bool>
        if itemString![identifier] != nil {
            checkbox.isChecked = itemString![identifier] as Bool!
        }
    }
}
```

Working code:

```
func onLoadSet(){
    identifier = "\(textLabel!.text!)\(rowCount)"
    //Set state from stored State
    if var storedToDoItems: AnyObject! = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("packItems") {

        if storedToDoItems != nil {
            println(storedToDoItems)
           var itemString = storedToDoItems as? Dictionary<String, Bool>
            if itemString![identifier] != nil {
                checkbox.isChecked = itemString![identifier] as Bool!
            } else {
                checkbox.isChecked = false
            }
        }
    }

}
```